# I anonymized my user-agent, but my browser and OS are still detected

Tags: browser, user-agent

There are sites like [whatsmybrowser.org](http://www.whatsmybrowser.org/) and [whatismybrowser.com](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/) that detect information about the technical specs of the client. As far as I can tell, this is done using the `user-agent` information sent by the browser on the HTTP requests.

What is puzzling me is that when I explicitly set my `user-agent` string to something random, in some cases it can still detect my browser and OS.

For example,  [whatbrowser.org](http://whatbrowser.org) knows I am using Firefox 31; and  [www.whatsmyua.com](http://www.whatsmyua.com) displays the following string:

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0

It looks strikingly like a user-agent.

[image]

But where is it being detected from? Firebug shows just `fake-user-agent` sent on the HTTP request headers.

If it matters, I am faking my user-agent using UAControl for Firefox ([pt-br version](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/uacontrol), [en-US version](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/uacontrol)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what those sites in particular are doing, but it is possible to probe a browser with JavaScript to detect its capabilities and identification. That is how [progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) is done.

Comment: I disabled my JavaScript. The two sites that detected my browser stopped detecting it.

Comment: It's quite obvious the sites are using client-side java to display the UA `function getUa() {
                    return location.hash.replace('#', '') || navigator.userAgent;
                }`

Comment: @qasdfdsaq What's blatantly obvious for some people might not be for others. Actually, that's kinda *the point of this entire site* ;-)